# Lock screen still displaying after login on resume?

Tags: login, suspend, 20.04

20.04 on a Thinkpad T420 with NVIDIA graphics. Sometimes when logging back in after waking from sleep, the title bar and dock will display normally but the desktop background is still blurred with the login prompt showing but not accepting input. Attempting to log out or restart will fail (display just stalls until power management turns it off) and launching any applications or terminal windows will not display them. Only resolution I can find is cutting power to reboot.

Any ideas how to resolve?